# Writing $a\leq x,y\leq b$ instead of $a\leq x\leq b\land a\leq y\leq b$

Tags: inequality, notation

If you have some function that has a restricted domain, e.g.

$c(x,y)=x+y,\ \ \ \  x \in \mathbb{Z}, y \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for}\ 1 \leq x \leq 3 \text{ and}\ \ 1 \leq y \leq 3$

then $c(x,y)$ can take the values from 2..to..6.

But is it possible to notate it like this?

$c(x,y)=x+y,\ \ \ \  x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for}\ 1 \leq x,y \leq 3$

Taken out of context, does $\ 1 \leq x,y \leq 3$ have a clear meaning?

Comment: It's a common notation, but it is ambiguous.

Comment: If the comma is inside the formula then it's one condition; otherwise it's two. If the font for math is sufficiently different from the font for text, you might see this. But you can't rely on typography...

Comment: $x,y \in [1,3]$ is a less ambiguous alternative